# MySQL: Join table on JSON field and get JSON data

Tags: mysql, sql, grafana

I want to create a table panel like this in Grafana:

```
+------------+--------------+------------------+
| Name       | Access level | Max Access level |
+------------+--------------+------------------+
| Tony Stark | 5            | 5                |
+------------+--------------+------------------+
```

This can be done by SQL query. I have MySQL as data source.

I have database called machines and personel.
Inside db machines I have tables for individual machines.

The table has id and json object as columns.

machines.machine_1

```
+----+---------------------------------------------+
| id | payload (JSON)                              |
+----+---------------------------------------------+
| 1  | {                                           |
|    |     "rack": {                               |
|    |         "0": {                              |
|    |             "internal": "20.42706840974966" |
|    |         }                                   |
|    |     },                                      |
|    |     "personel": {                           |
|    |         "id": "0xb7c9bd9bc1f7d852",         |
|    |         "access_level": "5",                |
|    |         "access_level_max": "5"             |
|    |     },                                      |
|    |     "information": {                        |
|    |         "ID": "machine_1"                   |
|    |     }                                       |
|    | }                                           |
+----+---------------------------------------------+
```

Then I have a table with personel inside the db personel.

personel.personel

```
+----+--------------------+------------+------+-------+----------+----------+-------------+
| id | hex                | name       | post | shift | superior | location | designation |
+----+--------------------+------------+------+-------+----------+----------+-------------+
| 1  | 0xb7c9bd9bc1f7d852 | Tony Stark | CEO  | NULL  | NULL     | NULL     | NULL        |
+----+--------------------+------------+------+-------+----------+----------+-------------+
```

Now,
I need to get data from the personel table according to the hex key from the json object that is
in machine_1.

I managed to do that like this:

```
SELECT
  name as "Name"
FROM personel.personel
  WHERE exists(
SELECT
    json_extract(payload, '$.personel.id')
FROM machines.machine_1 as Table_A
    ORDER BY arrived desc
LIMIT 1
)
```

I don't know, how to create a query, that would result in 3 columns, where the name is read from `personel.personel` identified by the value hex from json object in `machines.machine_1` and rest of the values are directly from the json object in `machines.machine_1`.

```
+------------+--------------+------------------+
| Name       | Access level | Max Access level |
+------------+--------------+------------------+
| Tony Stark | 5            | 5                |
+------------+--------------+------------------+
```

If this a incorrect way how to approach this kind of thing, please let me know.
I guess I can redo the solution, but I would like to stick to the JSON object because other reasons.

Thank you, for any kind of help.

Best regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below query can solve your problem:

```
select 
    p.name as 'Name',
    JSON_UNQUOTE(payload->"$.personel.access_level") as 'Access level',
    JSON_UNQUOTE(payload->"$.personel.access_level_max") as 'Max Access level'
from machines
left join personel p on p.hex = JSON_UNQUOTE(payload->"$.personel.id");
```

Try it on [SQLize.online](https://sqlize.online/?phpses=null&sqlses=7eed3056be2cfe544548c62c47d78e2b&php_version=null&sql_version=mysql80)

Comment: Thank you, very much.
I changed the querry a bit, so right now it looks like this.

select 
    p.name,
    JSON_UNQUOTE(payload->"$.personel.access_level") AS 'Access level',
    JSON_UNQUOTE(payload->"$.personel.access_level_max") AS 'Max Access level'
from machine_1
left join personel.personel p on p.hex = JSON_UNQUOTE(payload->"$.personel.id")
 ORDER BY arrived desc
LIMIT 1

Thank you, again.
Best rerads.